# Database for .NET development in mono

Tags: mono, database

I'm bit new to Linux. And want to develop .NET apps with MONO.
Actually its for my college project.
In windows we use MS SQL with MS visual studio,but problem is I cant find the perfect database replacement for MS SQL server which can I use with MONO.
any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is sort of the de-facto standard in Linux/Ubuntu. It also works with [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/mysql/). From the  link:

> The Mono provider for [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) database is the [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).
>
> MySQL Connector/Net is a fully managed provider and does not require a
>   client library. You have to get it from MySQL AB. The provider is
>   distributed under the GPL license. This is the recommened provider to
>   use with Mono.
>
> Support for MySQL Connector/Net can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/support/). If you decide to
>   compile from sources, you should define the conditional compilation
>   variable MONO (i.e., -d:MONO when compiling from the command line).
>   Usage
>
> Prerequisites
>
> ```
> MySQL database
>
> MySQL .NET Connector
> ```

Relevant part from the site about connecting:

```
 "Server=hostname;" + "Database=database;" + "User ID=username;" + 
 "Password=password;" + "Pooling=false"
```